# Protecting a worksheet but still allowing columns to be resized

Tags: xlsxwriter

I have been trying all combinations of protection options on a worksheet, but I don't seem to be able to find a combination that will allow columns to be resized but also lock cell value edits. The documentation is not clear on this either.

I have used format objects to lock individual cells and then called worksheet.protect with no password.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in Excel?